# How do I dynamically change a scrollbar background image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

This question is brutally difficult to ask in a clear fashion. But, I am going to try my best...

In the title, "scrollbar background" means the track area as shown in the following image (blatantly stolen from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41787/Creating-a-Blend-like-Scrollbar).

[Parts of a scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnXgv.png)

Apparently, stackoverflow will not allow me to embed images. So I hope the above link works.

Also, the word "dynamically" in the title does not mean swapping out one resource image for another. It means, create an image in memory and assign it to the scrollbar at run time.

I put together a simple project to demonstrate what I am trying to do. Here's a screenshot.

[Screenshot of desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbLUq.png)

Wait! Stop. Please don't suggest I "process out" to a third party app like Winmerge or whatever. Remember, this is just a demo app to help get the idea across. My real app is not comparing text files, although the end result will be very similar.

Here's s bit of the XAML of my demo app.

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dgDiffs" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <!--<ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding overview}" />-->
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="overview.png" />
                    </Setter.Value>
```

As you can see, I have hard coded an image for the demo (overview.png). You can also see where I tried to bind the image source to an object in C#. The idea being that I programmatically create a bitmap showing the overview, and then update the scrollbar.

And this is where I am stuck. I have tried creating simple bitmap objects and filling them with solid colors, but they do not appear on my scrollbar. I'm not even sure that I am taking the right approach.

Here's my demo code trying to use a bitmap object.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    class DiffItem {
        public int diff { get; set; } // used to color grid row (highlight differences)
        public string leftString { get; set; }
        public string rightString { get; set; }
    }

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        // build a lengthy list for demonstration
        List<DiffItem> diffList = new List<DiffItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // I've chopped out a bunch of lines here. This just builds a long repeating list for the demo
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "one", rightString = "one" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = -1, leftString = "four", rightString = "" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 1, leftString = "", rightString = "eight" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 2, leftString = "eleven", rightString = "elven" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "sixteen", rightString = "sixteen" });
        }

        // display list
        dgDiffs.ItemsSource = diffList;

        // update scrollbar overview
        Bitmap overview = new Bitmap(20, 200);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(overview)) {
            g.Clear(Color.Green);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the XAML trying to bind the scrollbar's image source.

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dgDiffs" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding diff}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding diff}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding diff}" Value="-1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding overview}" />
                        <!--<ImageBrush ImageSource="overview.png" />-->
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding leftString}" Width="200"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding rightString}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You are not expecting that `{Binding overview}` will bind to a *local variable* named overview? Besides that `Bitmap` is not a WPF class, wich you can't directly use as the ImageSource of an ImageBush.

Comment: Umm... yes? How is that different than {Binding diff}? Or "leftString," etc. Like I said, I don't even know if I am taking the right approach here. Also, how can I find the objects can be used as an image source?

Comment: Ok, you should stop here and read about some basics of WPF. Start here: [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview). WPF data binding works with public properties only.

Comment: The type of the ImageSource property is [ImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imagesource?view=netframework-4.7.2). You can hence assign types derived from ImageSource, and also string, Uri or byte[], because there is built-in automatic type conversion from these types. It is however unclear why you want to assign a bitmap at all. You may perhaps just want to use a LinearGradientBrush.

Comment: Ok, I see my confusion about ImageSource. Bitmap is derived from Image, so I made a bad assumption there. I'll read about the LinearGradientBrush to see if I can make multiple stripes with it.

Comment: It does not appear that the LinearGradientBrush will allow me to make distinct bands. Hopefully someone will be able to help me bind an image to the scrollbar background.

Comment: Note that Bitmap and Image from System.Drawing are WinForms classes. You usually do not use them in a WPF app. Do not confuse System.Drawing.Image with WPF's System.Windows.Controls.Image.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering... this is how to do it.

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dgDiffs" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding diff}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding diff}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding diff}" Value="-1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=overview}" />
                        <!--<ImageBrush ImageSource="overview.png" />-->
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding leftString}" Width="200"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding rightString}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    class DiffItem {
        public int diff { get; set; } // used to color grid row (highlight differences)
        public string leftString { get; set; }
        public string rightString { get; set; }
    }

    public BitmapImage overview { get; set; }

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        // build a lengthy list for demonstration
        List<DiffItem> diffList = new List<DiffItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "one", rightString = "one" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "two", rightString = "two" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "three", rightString = "three" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = -1, leftString = "four", rightString = "" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "five", rightString = "five" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "six", rightString = "six" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "seven", rightString = "seven" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 1, leftString = "", rightString = "eight" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "nine", rightString = "nine" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "ten", rightString = "ten" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 2, leftString = "eleven", rightString = "elven" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 2, leftString = "twelv", rightString = "twelve" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "thirteen", rightString = "thirteen" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "fourteen", rightString = "fourteen" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "fifteen", rightString = "fifteen" });
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem() { diff = 0, leftString = "sixteen", rightString = "sixteen" });
        }

        // display list
        dgDiffs.ItemsSource = diffList;

        // create the overview bitmap
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(20, 200, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
            Pen greenPen = new Pen(Color.Green, 1);
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            g.DrawLine(greenPen, 0, 50, 20, 50);
        }
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

        // load scrollbar with overview
        overview = new BitmapImage();
        overview.BeginInit();
        overview.StreamSource = memoryStream;
        overview.EndInit();
        overview.Freeze();
    }
}
```